# Accessing HBase REST API through Java Applet

Tags: java, rest, applet, hbase

I am currently writing a small Java applet to access HBase data using the REST API. Accessing the data using Java is not particularly difficult, I have done this successfully. When running on a machine in my HDP cluster, the results are perfect. However when running as an applet I get no results at all. (I have chosen an applet since distributing an executable JAR is something my boss wants to avoid)

Having finally found what I believe to be the underlying issue, I have found the following runtime exception: `hbase-default.xml file seems to be for an older version of HBase (null), this version is 1.1.2.2.4.0.0-169`. My assumption is that this is caused by the fact that my local machine does not have HBase at all. The intention is that users will be able to view their own data from a local machine, and so I cannot expect all users to have HBase (or anything other than a browser)

My question really has two parts:

- Is there anyway to get an applet like this to work?
- Is there a better alternative to an applet for this kind of work?

Posting my code in case I have made some significant mistake:

```
public class HBaseConnector extends JApplet
{
    private Cluster cluster;

    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Applet initialising");
        cluster = new Cluster();
        cluster.add("hbase_server", 9080);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Applet starting");
        Client client = new Client(cluster);
        RemoteHTable table = new RemoteHTable(client, "table_name");
        Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("key"));
        get.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("f1"), Bytes.toBytes("Record"));
        try
        {
            Result result1 = table.get(get);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Bytes.toString(result1.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("f1"), Bytes.toBytes("Record"))), "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception occurred");
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Applet stopping");
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("Applet destroyed");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"(I have chosen an applet since distributing an executable JAR is something my boss wants to avoid)"* Why does the boss 'want to avoid' that? I can almost guarantee that distribution as an applet will **not** fix the perceived problem. And while on the subject of applets: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception occurred");
        }` ...

Comment: .. Change that to `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }` which provides more information for less typing. 3) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Firstly I really didn't know about the Java Console (I haven't made an applet in ~7 years). Secondly, I moved away from an applet to a JNLP application, which solved my problem. This suggests that the underlying issue was to do the with the applet sandbox security. Again, thank you.

Comment: Right you are. Will do so now.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't been able to solve this problem for an applet itself, I managed to get the app working by moving over the a JNLP app ([JNLP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html)). Given this, I suspect the underlying problem was a permissions issue due to the fact that applets run in a sandbox. This is fine, since I am aware that most browsers are moving away from Java plugins.

Another possible cause I discovered: hbase-default.xml must be in the root folder of the jar.